# crossdomain.xml workaround without access to root of vhost

Tags: jwplayer, crossdomain.xml

I'm trying to use a playlist XML file with JW Player which requires crossdomain.xml to live in the domain's root directory. I do not have read/write access to the domain's root directory, however.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can use 'playlistfile' rather than 'file' in the jwplayer JSON configuration to specify the URL to the XML playlist, and then crossdomain.xml is unnecessary.